# How to programmatically remove headers and footers in print pages on Safari with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, safari

I am having trouble removing the header and footer from print pages in Safari using JavaScript. While I know that in most browsers, the header and footer can be manually disabled through the user's print settings, my goal is to automate this process with code so that users do not see the headers and footers when printing web page content.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Xti.png)

Does anyone know how to accomplish this programmatically in Safari? Or is there an alternative way to circumvent the default print settings in Safari?

Thank you!

my goal is to automate this process with code so that users do not see the headers and footers when printing web page content.

Comment: Have you looked at @media print CSS queries?

Comment: if I understand you right, then there is no way to remove the print header and footers that coming from the printer and not the HTML file. Those headers and footers are browser and PC-controlled headers and footers. Those are user-controlled settings and are out of reach of the developer for obvious security reasons

Comment: @tacoshy thanks for the clarification, I think I had misunderstood the question to mean the generated header/footer. If so your comment is correct.

Comment: @A Haworth ,@tacoshy "You are correct, Safari does not support controlling the 'Header and Footer' options of the print dialog through JavaScript."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no straightforward way to remove those two options from the print screen with JavaScript. Safari does not provide a direct API for manipulating those print settings like some other browsers do. However, you can try the following to exclude the footer and the header during the print state:

```
@media print {
    @page {
        margin: 0;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    header, footer {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I have now learned some new knowledge: Safari does not support controlling the 'Header and Footer' options of the print dialog through JavaScript.